# Is it possible to link multiple google analytics properties in a single Bigquery project?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

I want to know if it is possible to link multiple different google analytics properties in a single Bigquery project by separating the property datasets by properties.
I checked the acceptance message that the linking is going well, but I have no idea that the data will be saved in a dataset or different datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to link multiple GA properties to a single GCP Project but in different BigQuery datasets. In case of Universal Analytics, the ID of each BQ dataset will be same as that of GA View ID. And in case of GA4 the ID of each BQ dataset will be `analytics_<property_id>`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This answer is a crucial key for me!:D